# Can I add every function to my .cpp

Tags: c++

I have 2 questions about file size and performance

Would adding every function to a .cpp even when i only use it from the CPP make my program larger/slower?

CPP

```
void Thing::Meme(void)
{
    this->Think();
    printf("Hello\n");
}
```

H

```
#pragma once

class Thing
{
    void Think(void);
    void Meme(void);
}
```

Would using the "this->" pointer on every function in the same class be the same as not using it?

Thanks.

Comment: be quick and make your question title much more specific, otherwise you'll receive a slew of downvotes

Comment: One question by question. Even more when they are unrelated.

Comment: There's no difference in binary file size and/or speed (with or without this and/or file separation)

Comment: What do you mean by "every function"? Every function out of what? "Larger" how? "Slower" how? Under what specific circumstances? And why did you append a random unrelated question about `this->`? This question has not been well thought out at all.

Comment: I don't advise placing every function into one cpp file; maintenance nightmare.  For example, at my shop, some files are over 4500 lines of code.  Yes, placing all the functions into one file will save you space on the hard drive, due to the lack of overhead (file name, directory entries, et. al.).  As far as build time, no it will not speed up the build.  The quantity of files does not affect the performance of your executable; the amount of code does.

Answer (score 0):

Adding all functions won't affect the runtime but might slightly increase the compilation time .

Calling a function via a function pointer is somewhat slower than a static function call, since the former call includes an extra pointer de-referencing.
But i don't think that there will be any significant difference in the runtime on any modern machine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding all the functions of a program into a single source file will save room on your hard drive.  For every file, there is some overhead, such as the file name and a directory entry.  However, with today's Gigabyte and Terabyte size hard drives, the amount of space you save is negligible (Do the math 100 bytes / 1 gigabyte).

One file for all the functions in a program, may save time on the build process.  Finding files on the hard drive does take some time, but again, it is negligible.  Also, there is a small amount of time taken up by opening and closing files; again, not really measurable (we're talking milliseconds, compared to human interaction time in tenths of seconds).

The number of functions in a file has no correlation to the performance of an executable.  The number of functions in the entire program, is relevant.  A program with one source file versus the same program with 50 files, will have the same executable performance.

A big issue is that if you modify one function, the entire behemoth must be rebuilt, thus taking a long time.  By splitting up into smaller files, only the files that were modified need to be compiled, thus making the build process faster.

Splitting up your files by theme or class, makes re-use a lot easier. If my program has a Car class and an Ingredient class, all in one file, I can't reuse the Car class without also include the Ingredient class.  However, if the Car class and Ingredient are in separate files, I can re-use the Ingredient class without compiling the Car class.

> Would using the "this->" pointer on every function in the same class be the same as not using it?

Please, don't use `this->` syntax.  For every class, there is only one instance of its methods.  This kind of worry or optimization is considered *micro-optimization*.  You will waste a lot of development time worrying or performing micro-optimization.  Focus on software design and program correctness.  Let the compiler worry about pointers to functions, if it desires to use them.  By the way, during development, one change in one method may affect your micro-optimizations with another method.  Wait until your program works correctly, then optimize as necessary (after profiling).